# Discord.py bot speak message

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py, message, text-to-speech

I have been looking for a way to make a bot speak out loud an edited message, using `tts=True` works fine when the message is first send. However, it doesn't work when it is edited. Here is the code I have tried.

```
msg = await ctx.send(content='Hello world', tts=True)

await msg.edit(content="I said hello", tts=True)
```

Couldn't find anything on google. Hopefully, somebody here knows how to do it.

Comment: Another option is delete it and send a new one. I know this is not what you asked for but it will work.

Comment: As far as I know TTS only works on the initial message send

Comment: Wow!, not exactly what I had in mind but delete it and send a new one worked just fine.